# Case condition & Instring function in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table in my oracle database with the varchar2 column 'Detail_Number' with records as can be seen below-

```
Detail_Number
--------------
P1464187
1-17J3P
VAR1460621
P15000566
VRH-P146310034
RH-73082_SS1
19502744
```

Now, I want to use a case statement which returns me only the portion of the Detail_Number column before the special character '_' in case the special character is present. Else, just return me the Detail_Number.

The case statement I have written is -

```
CASE
  WHEN INSTR(A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER, '_') IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTR(A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER, 0, INSTR(A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER, '_')-1)
  WHEN INSTR(A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER, '_') = 0 THEN A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER
  --ELSE A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER
END AS Output
```

The result of the query is as below -

```
Detail_Number   Output
-------------   --------
P1464187    
1-17J3P 
VAR1460621  
P15000566   
VRH-P146310034  
RH-73082_SS1    RH-73082
19502744
```

Here, I am getting the portion after '_' getting skipped. But, in case '_' is not present, it returns me null. Can u please help me with the same.

Thanks.

Comment: What are your desired results?

Comment: I figured out the solution -

Comment: CASE
  WHEN INSTR(A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER, '_') <> 0 THEN SUBSTR(A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER, 0, INSTR(A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER, '_')-1)
  WHEN INSTR(A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER, '_') = 0 THEN A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER
  --ELSE A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER
END AS Output

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean this?

```
SQL> with
  2    data as (select 'P1464187' t# from dual union all
  3             select '1-17J3P' t# from dual union all
  4             select 'VAR1460621' t# from dual union all
  5             select 'P15000566' t# from dual union all
  6             select 'VRH-P146310034' t# from dual union all
  7             select 'RH-73082_SS1' t# from dual union all
  8             select '19502744' t# from dual)
  9  select
 10    substr(t#, 1, instr(t# || '_', '_') - 1)
 11  from
 12    data;

SUBSTR(T#,1,INSTR(T#||'_','_')-1)
--------------------------------------------------------
P1464187
1-17J3P
VAR1460621
P15000566
VRH-P146310034
RH-73082
19502744

7 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using REGEXP_REPLACE (probably not as efficient in large builk as Sanders INSTR option ;)  (but still effective)

```
  with w_data as ( 
        select rtrim('P1464187      ') c from dual union all
        select rtrim('1-17J3P       ') c from dual union all
        select rtrim('VAR1460621    ') c from dual union all
        select rtrim('P15000566     ') c from dual union all
        select rtrim('VRH-P146310034') c from dual union all
        select rtrim('RH-73082_SS1  ') c from dual union all
        select rtrim('19502744      ') c from dual
        )
  Select c, regexp_replace(c, '^(.*)[_$]','\1') d
  from w_data;


  C              D
  -------------- ----------------------------------------
  P1464187       P1464187
  1-17J3P        1-17J3P
  VAR1460621     VAR1460621
  P15000566      P15000566
  VRH-P146310034 VRH-P146310034
  RH-73082_SS1   RH-73082SS1
  19502744       19502744

  7 rows selected.
```